# T-sql select statement - multiple column with Case statement yes or no based on another table data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL `select` statement with multiple columns with `Case` statements yes or no based on another table data

I have these two tables:

**table1**

```
Id  | Location
----+------------
101 | Warsaw
102 | Belfast
104 | Singapore
106 | Texas
108 | Mumbai
109 | Virgina
```

**table2**:

```
Id  | AttrName   | AttrId
----+------------+---------
101 | Datacenter | 99
101 | Cold       | 88
102 | Datacenter | 99
102 | Cold       | 88
106 | Datacenter | 99
108 | Cold       | 88
```

The query output should be:

```
Id  | Location  | Datacenter | Cold 
----+-----------+------------+------
101 | Warsaw    | YES        | YES 
102 | Belfast   | YES        | YES 
104 | Singapore | NO         | NO  
106 | Texas     | YES        | NO  
108 | Mumbai    | NO         | YES 
109 | Virgina   | NO         | NO
```

Please let me know how we can achieve this.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. And why the `sp` tag?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code or SQL writing service. We expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so and run into difficulties, you can explain what you're trying to do and the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll be glad to try to help. Your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], before you begin posting here.

Comment: This is the query I have tried in isql and it worked. I'm working to accomplish in mssql.
select a.id, a.Location,'Datacenter' =case when b1.AttrId=99 then 'yes' else 'No' end,'Cold'=case when b2.AttrId=88 then 'yes' else 'No' end
from table1 a, (select Id,AttrId from table2 b where AttrId=99) b1, (select Id,AttrId from table2 b where AttrId=88) b2
where a.Id*=b1.Id and a.Id*=b2.Id

Answer (score 0):

1. Simple but not optimized approach:   You need to LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 to table1 as many times as many AttrName's you would like to put in different columns in the final result. Each join should use a different alias name for table2 and filter on a specific AttrName:

```sql
FROM table1 as base
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 as Datacenter on base.Id = Datacenter.Id and Datacenter.AttrName = 'Datacenter'
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 as Cold on base.Id = Cold.Id and Cold.AttrName = 'Cold'
```

In the SELECT you need to check for the existence of matching lookup to the specific alias of table2 to define a column deriving from AttrName:

```
CASE WHEN Datacenter.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as Datacenter
```

2. Advanced and likely more optimized approach:
   Use [Utrolig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310200/t-sql-select-statement-multiple-column-with-case-statement-yes-or-no-based-on/53314822#53314906): PIVOT should outperform due to less lookups (but always look at query plans when you optimize code!)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PIVOT instead. It can perform better, but I'd check the execution plans on each to be sure. Just be sure to redirect my query to the real tables (instead of these table variables for testing) before you compare plans. Good luck! :)

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Location VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE CLUSTERED (Id)
);

INSERT INTO @Table1
(Id, Location)
VALUES
(101,'Warsaw'),
(102,'Belfast'),
(104,'Singapore'),
(106,'Texas'),
(108,'Mumbai'),
(109,'Virgina');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    AttrName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    AttrId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE CLUSTERED (Id,AttrId)
);

INSERT INTO @Table2
(Id, AttrName, AttrId)
VALUES
(101,'Datacenter',99),
(101,'Cold',88),
(102,'Datacenter',99),
(102,'Cold',88),
(106,'Datacenter',99),
(108,'Cold',88);

WITH CTE_Table2 AS (
    SELECT
        Id,
        Datacenter,
        Cold
    FROM (
        SELECT
            t.Id,
            t.AttrName,
            'YES' AS Bool
        FROM @Table2 AS t
    ) AS b
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Bool)
        FOR AttrName IN ([Datacenter],[Cold])
    ) AS p
)

SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t1.Location,
    ISNULL(t2.Datacenter,'NO') AS Datacenter,
    ISNULL(t2.Cold,'NO') AS Cold
FROM @Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN CTE_Table2 AS t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id;
```

Comment: As an extra note here... the comments on your main post about putting in real effort is important. The only reason I'm helping in this case is because you're new to SO. It takes some getting used to. I hope my SQL can actually help your situation.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to update my comments with the query I have used before in isql ( it works) but in mssql it's not working. Also I want to update the query in my question, it's not allowing to update it( Format issue).

Comment: Sorry @MTCEntertainment, does that mean this worked for you? Do you still need assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Below is other option to resolve, it uses `EXISTS`,

```
-- delcare table variables
declare @t1 table (Id int, Location nvarchar(20))
declare @t2 table (Id int, AttrName nvarchar(20), AttrId int)

-- insert test data
insert into @t1
values (101, 'Warsaw'),
    (102, 'Beflast'),
    (104, 'Singapore'),
    (106, 'Texas'),
    (108, 'Mumbai'),
    (109, 'Virginia')

insert into @t2
values (101, 'Datacentre', 99),
    (101, 'Cold', 88),
    (102, 'Datacentre', 99),
    (102, 'Cold', 88),
    (106, 'Datacentre', 99),
    (108, 'Cold', 88)

-- query
select 
    t1.Id,
    Location, 
    case when exists (select 1 from @t2 t2 where t2.AttrId = 99 and t1.id = t2.id) then 'yes' else 'no' end as Datacentre,
    case when exists (select 1 from @t2 t2 where t2.AttrId = 88 and t1.id = t2.id) then 'yes' else 'no' end as Cold
from @t1 t1
```

**Result**

```
Id  Location    Datacentre  Cold
101 Warsaw          yes     yes
102 Beflast         yes     yes
104 Singapore       no      no
106 Texas           yes     no
108 Mumbai          no      yes
109 Virginia        no      no
```

Comment: Thank you. let me try this.

Comment: @MTCEntertainment, add comment if something is unclear.